# Finding children in a tree using F#

Tags: .net, f#, tree

I am attempting to model a simple tree structure using F# and cannot help thinking that I am doing this very badly:

My tree is essentially a list of leaves (which will ultimately be persisted to a database table). I have a function getChildren that receives a leaf NodeID and recursively returns all the children of that leaf.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type leaf = { nodeID : int; nodeDescr : string; parentID : int option}

let myTree = [ { nodeID = 0;  nodeDescr = "Root"; parentID = None };
                 { nodeID = 1;  nodeDescr = "Mechanical"; parentID = Some(0) } ;
                 { nodeID = 2;  nodeDescr = "Electrical"; parentID = Some(0) } ;
                 { nodeID = 3;  nodeDescr = "High Voltage"; parentID = Some(2) } ;
                 { nodeID = 4;  nodeDescr = "Low Voltage"; parentID = Some(2) } ;
                 { nodeID = 5;  nodeDescr = "HV Maintanence"; parentID = Some(3) } ;
                 { nodeID = 6;  nodeDescr = "City Power"; parentID = Some(3) } ;
                 { nodeID = 7;  nodeDescr = "LV Wiring"; parentID = Some(4) } ;
                 { nodeID = 8;  nodeDescr = "LV Maintanence"; parentID = Some(4) } ]


let getChildren (id : int) (tree : list<leaf>) = 
    let allChildren = new List<leaf>() // Mutable list

    let rec getAllChildren (id : int) (t : list<leaf>) = 
        let cl = List.filter (fun x -> x.parentID = Some id) t // Get the immediate children
        for c in cl do // Loop through the immediate children and recursively get their children
            allChildren.Add(c)
            getAllChildren c.nodeID t
    getAllChildren id tree
    allChildren
```

The concerns I have here are :

1. I am using a mutable list
2. I am using looping

I suspect that there is a more elegant approach to all this when using functional programming in F# which avoids mutation and loops, and that my imperative programming habits are sneaking through.

Also, is this a good way to model a tree structure, bearing in mind that it will need to be stored and retrieved from a database table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep the tree structure you already have, this function would find children for you, without looping or mutable values:

```
let getChildren (id : int) (tree : list<leaf>) = 
    let parent node = tree |> Seq.filter (fun x -> Some x.nodeID = node.parentID) |> Seq.exactlyOne

    let rec hasAncestor (node : leaf) =
        node.parentID = Some id || (node.parentID.IsSome && hasAncestor (parent node))

    tree |> Seq.filter hasAncestor
```

But probably what you really want is a structure where each node stores a reference to its children, and you when you go to serialize the data you can find the ID from the reference

Something like this should hopefully be enough to point you in the right direction:

```
type Node = {
    Id : int;
    Description: string;
    Children: seq<Node>
}

let myTree =
    { Id = 0; Description = "Root"; Children = 
    [
        { Id = 1; Description = "Mechanical"; Children = [] };
        { Id = 2; Description = "Electrical"; Children =         
        [
            { Id = 3; Description = "High Voltage"; Children = 
            [
                { Id = 5; Description = "HV Maintanence"; Children = [] };
                { Id = 6; Description = "City Power"; Children = [] }
            ] };
            { Id = 4; Description = "Low Voltage"; Children = 
            [
                { Id = 7; Description = "LV Wiring"; Children = [] } ;
                { Id = 8; Description = "LV Maintanence"; Children = [] }
            ] }
        ]};
    ]}

let rec getChildren (node : Node) = 
    Seq.concat [node.Children; (Seq.collect getChildren node.Children)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like your implementation of getChildren.